# CSS button background images won't appear

Tags: html, css

I'm using Chrome and I'm trying to make a background button image appear. But it just won't show! I (think I) have tried everything.

I've added: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css" />`

**1. HTML**

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="#" /> Home</a>
    <a href="#" /> About</a>
    <a href="#" /> Sign Up</a>
    <a href="#" /> Sign In</a>
    <a href="#" /> Impressum</a>
</div>`
```

**2. CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-width:1280px) {
    #menu {
        background-image: url('../img/menubg.png');
        position: absolute;
        top:0px;
        right:0px;
        height: 37px;
        padding-top: 19px;
        margin-right: 4%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1280px) {
    #menu {
        background-image: url('../img/menubg.png');
        position: absolute;
        top:0px;
        right:0px;
        height: 37px;
        padding-top: 19px;
        margin-right: 6%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1920px) {
    #menu {
        background-image: url('../img/menubg.png');
        position: absolute;
        top:0px;
        right:0px;
        height: 37px;
        padding-top: 19px;
        margin-right: 10%;
    }
}

#menu a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-image: url('../img/menubg.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top: 19px;
    padding-bottom: 22px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

#menu a:hover {
    background-image: url('../img/menubg.png');
}
```

Comment: Are any of the other CSS rules being applied? Check the URL for the CSS reference. The leading forward slash only has a single period in front of it, shouldn't that be two?

Comment: Open console and see if the background is found.

Comment: Try removing the `/>` at the end of the links and just putting `>`
Also, show us your folder structure.

Comment: Hey Mr Jack! Ive change /> to >. That didnt solve it. My folder structure to the image is: C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\testings\img    Furthermore, yes, there are other css codes being applied, but they dont refer to the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I noticed that you were changing the position of the menu based on the screen width so I'm guessing that you were trying to centre it. So I removed the media tags and now there's only one `#menu` css part.

If I interpreted this incorrectly, then simply revert it back to what you had before.

As for the background-image, what you currently have works. So I'm guessing that your link to the image is wrong. If you open developer tools and inspect one the anchors the background-image attribute will be crossed out if your link to the image is invalid.

As proof that it does work I added a random image from google:

```css
#menu{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    text-align:center;
    background-color:blue;
}

#menu a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRtXT6s3Qg8rFrxuDbC2mI7df8ef3CBq4W9wNE8r1lwb991vs_x');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 19px 10px 22px 10px;
}

#menu a:hover {
    background-image: url('../img/menubg.png');
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <a href="#" > Home</a>
    <a href="#" > About</a>
    <a href="#" > Sign Up</a>
    <a href="#" > Sign In</a>
    <a href="#" > Impressum</a>
</div>
```

```
<style>
#menu{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    text-align:center;
    background-color:blue;
}

#menu a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRtXT6s3Qg8rFrxuDbC2mI7df8ef3CBq4W9wNE8r1lwb991vs_x');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 19px 10px 22px 10px;
}

#menu a:hover {
    background-image: url('../img/menubg.png');
}
</style>
<div id="menu">
    <a href="#" > Home</a>
    <a href="#" > About</a>
    <a href="#" > Sign Up</a>
    <a href="#" > Sign In</a>
    <a href="#" > Impressum</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey there, thank you so much for your time to respond to my question. It's really odd. When I run the code snippet here on stackoverflow, it works. If I run the code through my file on to any browser, the buttons don't seem to pull the CSS code. Even if I get the image from the www, I only see html on my buttons. Even odder is, that the CSS codes for my header and my logo all seem to work.

Comment: Okay, try using an internal style sheet instead: your href may be wrong in your link tag. ie have a html document with only the code I edited in above: then we know it's the link that's wrong.

Comment: What do you mean with "internal" style sheet? :)

Comment: Ah okay, there's 3 ways to implement your css into your code. Internal is when you use the <style></style> tags in the <head> of the document. :)

Comment: This explains that difference very well: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)

Comment: Cool! :) However, this is only half the problem. You can use this by all means but you probably don't want all that code in one place. This tells us your `href` attribute in your `link` tag was wrong. So if you get the correct `href` you wont need an internal style sheet! :)